# How to follow IntelliJ-IDEA's advice "catch branch identical" on try/catch block?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, serialization, exception, try-catch

I'm using "ObjectInputStream" to load serialized 2D String arrays.

The problem is, My IDE, Intellij-IDEA, will throw an error unless I put a special catch condition for a ClassNotFoundException. However, when I do that it advises, "`'catch' branch identical to 'IOException' branch`".

I don't know what this is implying I should do.

*How can I load serialized objects without getting either advice or an error?*

**My code:**

```
private String[][] getPossArray(String race, boolean isFirstName) {
    String[][] retVal = new String[0][];

    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("./res/binary_files/Human_FirstNameString[][].ser");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        retVal = (String[][]) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: `catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e)` and remove second `catch` block

Comment: @guleryuz Thanks! That works! If you put that in an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: It's not a compilation error or a warning, it's a  suggestion from IDEA on how you can improve the code piece.

Comment: That warning says you jdk is >1.7 so use multi catch block instead of branching @LuminousNutria

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Oh, I guess I'm not sure how to tell the difference. Sorry about that. I'll rephrase my question to account for it.

Comment: @Deadpool I think that's what guleryuz just told me to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to guleryuz's comment, I found out that the advice from IntelliJ was trying to tell me that I could get rid of the advice notification by changing my catch block to `catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e)` instead of having each catch statement on it's own line.

**Old Catch-Block Version:**

```
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**New Catch-Block Version:**

```
} catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The quickest way to do this is press Alt+Enter on the warning and invoke *Collapse 'catch' blocks*.